# Remove a specific cookie using php

Tags: php, cookies

What I have understood it's possible to remove a cookie with PHP if you know it's name, but there is one catch.

I have a subdomain in witch I have changed how Google Analytics tracks. This means I now have two _ga cookies with different domains. They are:
_ga cookie with domain set to "site.com"
_ga cookie with domain set to "subdomain.site.com"

Is it possible to delete the _ga cookie that uses "subdomain.site.com" when users visits the page? Or at least set expiry date to something in the past?

Kind regards
Johan

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share cookie between subdomain and domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain)

Comment: @WillParky93 I do not see how this is a duplicate of the "share cookie" question? :-)

Comment: Sorry I should have wrote something like; Maybe this may have the solution for you. It specifies how the root domain can access a subdomain cookie and vise versa. If your setup doesn't follow the same rules you could say that it's not possible.